# How can I place an updating matplotlib chart into a webpage?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've created an **updating** matplotlib chart in Python 3.7. It updates every minute. I'd like to show the chart in my Google Slides presentation. Therefore I want to put the updating chart into a webpage that I can show in my presentation. How could this be done?

Answer (score 4):

Use the webagg backend.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("webagg")
```

You can customize the address and port via [rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html):

```
## The port to use for the web server in the WebAgg backend.
#webagg.port : 8988

## The address on which the WebAgg web server should be reachable
#webagg.address : 127.0.0.1
```